R sentiment.ai package install on OSX 14.4.1, with Apple Silicon processor M2
I am trying to install the sentiment.ai R package on an OSX machine with an M2 processor. I get this error:
install.packages("sentiment.ai")
library(sentiment.ai)

install_sentiment.ai()
Error in .make_numeric_version(x, strict, .standard_regexps()$valid_numeric_version) :
invalid non-character version specification 'x' (type: double)

I cannot go beyond that error. I uninstalled and reinstalled R and RStudio. A friend told me it works on an Intel machine, but I don't have one.

What's with the python tag? Don't spam tags please. [ask]

The Python tag is related to this package because sentiment.ai uses TensorFlow, which is a Python package but works under R through reticulate.

I think this question would be more appropriate as an issue in the corresponding GitHub repository

I already asked in the GitHub repository but got no answer, so I tried my luck here.

Please include links to the GitHub issue.

Here is the link: https://github.com/BenWiseman/sentiment.ai/issues/21

Try the openai_addin branch. There is a patch to the install script that seems to work on Apple Silicone. Let me know if that works and I'll push that to CRAN

Please provide more information about the openai_add in branch and why you think this would work in this case.

Because I also patched in logic to install differently on M2. You are free to look at the change history if you're interested.

I have managed to make it work. I installed Python 3.12 through conda. I created the r-virtual-ai environment. The problem was tensorflow_text. This package can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/sun1638650145/Libraries-and-Extensions-for-TensorFlow-for-Apple-Silicon/releases. Then I installed the whl file, pip. install Downloads/tensorflow_text-2.16.1-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl After this, run init_sentiment.ai() was the last function to be called. One should not forget to choose the Python version in Tools > Global Options.

I have managed to make it work.
I installed Python 3.12 through conda.
I created the r-virtual-ai environment.
The problem was tensorflow_text.
This package can be downloaded from here: github.com/sun1638650145/….
Then I installed the whl file, pip. install Downloads/tensorflow_text-2.16.1-cp312-cp312-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
After this, run init_sentiment.ai() was the last function to be called.
One should not forget to choose the Python version in Tools > Global Options.
